# Using cumprod() to calculate equity curve in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, return, algorithmic-trading

I am having difficulty calculating a compounding return using cumprod(). It starts compounding from the very beginning, but I only want it to start when 'Final_Order' equals buy and stop when 'Final_Order equal sell, and then reset again on the next buy order. Please see the example below.

Sample data below shows the output I expect to see for column 'Backtest'.

```
 Time  Adj_Price  Final_Order   Backtest
  0        7          nan          1000
  1        6          nan          1000
  2        5          Buy          1000
  3        7          Buy          1400
  4        8          Sell         1600
  5        6          Sell         1600
  6        4          Buy          1600
  7        5          Buy          2000
  8        7          Buy          2800
  9        9          Sell         3600
  10       7          Sell         3600
  11       7          Sell         3600
  12       6          Sell         3600
```

Below are calculations for 'Backtest'.

- Time 1 =IF(Final_Order ="Buy(t0)",(6/7)*1000, Else 1000) = 1000
- Time 2 =IF(Final_Order ="Buy(t1)",(5/6)*1000, Else 1000) = 1000
- Time 3 =IF(Final_Order ="Buy(t2)",(7/5)*1000, Else 1000) = 1400
- Time 4 =IF(Final_Order ="Buy(t3)",(8/7)*1400, Else 1400) = 1600
- Time 5 =IF(Final_Order ="Buy(t4)",(6/8)*1600, Else 1600) = 1600
- Time 6 =IF(Final_Order ="Buy(t5)",(4/6)*1600, Else 1600) = 1600
- Time 7 =IF(Final_Order ="Buy(t6)",(5/4)*1600, Else 1600) = 2000
- Time 8 =IF(Final_Order ="Buy(t7)",(7/5)*2000, Else 2000) = 2800
- Time 9 =IF(Final_Order ="Buy(t8)",(9/7)*2800, Else 2800) = 3600
- Time 10 =IF(Final_Order ="Buy(t9)",(7/9)*3600,Else 3600) = 3600

Below is the code I am working with.

```
data['Backtest'] = np.where(data['Final_Order'] == 'Buy',
                            ((1 + data['Adj 
Close'].pct_change(1)).cumprod())*1000,
                            data['Backtest'].ffill())
```

Comment: What is benchmark?

Comment: Should say 'Backtest', not benchmark. I have made the correction

Comment: `t9` is sell. How do you get 3600??

Comment: @Onyambu It is based on the previous day's 'Final_Order'. The price is based on Closing price, so I technically wouldnt sell until the following morning. In the IF statements, you'll see that Final_Order = Buy(**t8**).

Comment: am talking of t10 which takes t9

Comment: Your explanation is not clear. In the ifstatement there is no cumprod. But in your code you have cumprod.

Comment: @Onyambu Sorry, that is a typo, I made the correction

Comment: where are you getting the else values from? or the values you are using to compute eg 1000,1400,1600 etc where do you get them from?

Comment: @Onyambu Assuming you start at $1,000 , and a buy triggers at Time 2 at $5 and the next day it closes at $7 = > (7/5)*1000 = $1400

Comment: That makes sence: okay you can do `list(itertools.accumulate([1000]+list(zip(df.Adj_Price.shift(-1)/df.Adj_Price,df.Final_Order)),lambda x,y: round(y[0]*x) if y[1]=="Buy" else x))[1:]`

Comment: @Onyambu I am getting the following error: **name 'itertools' is not defined**

Comment: import itertools it is a module

Comment: @Onyambu Its working but its not looking at the previous day's 'Final_Order'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list whose initial value is 1000 and has the rate and the Final Order:

```
b = [1000]+list(zip(df.Adj_Price.shift(-1)/df.Adj_Price,df.Final_Order))

df['BACK']=list(itertools.accumulate(b,lambda x,y: round(y[0]*x) if y[1]=="Buy" else x))[:-1]

df

    Time  Adj_Price Final_Order  Backtest  BACK
0      0          7         NaN      1000  1000
1      1          6         NaN      1000  1000
2      2          5         Buy      1000  1000
3      3          7         Buy      1400  1400
4      4          8        Sell      1600  1600
5      5          6        Sell      1600  1600
6      6          4         Buy      1600  1600
7      7          5         Buy      2000  2000
8      8          7         Buy      2800  2800
9      9          9        Sell      3600  3600
10    10          7        Sell      3600  3600
11    11          7        Sell      3600  3600
12    12          6        Sell      3600  3600
```

Comparing the column created to the one already present, They are identical

Comment: this is not working, I am getting the following error: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Comment: It looks like it might have something to do with Adj_Price having decimals.